# Several Domain PC's Won't Ping

Tags: dns, dhcp, ping, anti-virus, domain

I have close to half of my workstations that the domain controller (also the DHCP/DNS server) and my PC can no longer ping. Those PC's CAN ping TO the domain controller and other PC's.

We did migrate from Symantec Endpoint to WebRoot Secure Anywhere Endpoint and I think something happened there, either with leftover Symantec, Windows Firewall, WebRoot or all three. I also manually went into the group policy of each workstation and disabled Windows Defender, since WebRoot doesn't do this.

I uninstalled Symantec from the Domain Controller and File Server but didn't not install WebRoot as of yet.  I've opened a case with Symantec for their cleanwipe tool but they've not responded.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Windows firewall?

Comment: I removed your commentary from your question.  Please do not submit this question to multiple SE websites.  Your need for a solution "right away" isn't a valid reason to cross-post it to multiple StackExchange websites

Comment: I've tried turning Windows Firewall off and it didn't affect anything. I've checked the Firewall on the Domain Controller, thinking perhaps something was changed there when removing Symantec and it still looks good.

Comment: In addition, if this helps...I was also able to hit every C$ share and use COMPUTER MANAGEMENT REMOTELY...all of that died about the time of the Endpoint migration...